# Create grid view like pinterest app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

can anyone help me by telling me how can I create a layout like this one:
[image]

It looks like a grid view, but not all items have the same width, and height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a modified version of Android's experimental StaggeredGridView. The StaggeredGridView allows the user to create a GridView with uneven rows similar to how Pinterest looks. Includes own OnItemClickListener and OnItemLongClickListener, selector, and fixed position restore.

Refer [this](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo),It may help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a well supported library https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid

Answer (score -1):

Another view that I found now, thanks to @AndroidLearner is PinterestLikeAdapterView you can check it [here](https://github.com/huewu/PinterestLikeAdapterView). If anyone also has the problem like me - you can refer to this one also.

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary) is definitely what are you looking for. The other example given in the answers does not allow you to manipulate with the width of the items, with this one you are able to do anything.